# Notice: Undefined index: submitbutton

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy atascado un poco, ¿me pueden ayudar?, estoy empezando a programar en `PHP`, porque un amigo mío me lo recomienda, pero he tenido este problema por un tiempo

```html
    <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

              <!--      Wizard container        -->
              <div class="wizard-container">
                  <div class="card wizard-card" data-color="orange" id="wizardProfile">

                    <div class="wizard-header text-center">
                           <h3 class="wizard-title">Sign Up</h3>
                          <p class="category">Create a profile and fill it with your information.</p>
                   </div>

                    <br/>

                    <div id="sign"class="row ">


                    <form class="formget " action="" method="post">
                      <div class="">
                        <input class="formember" type="text" name="user" value="" placeholder="Usuario">
                      </div>
                      <div class="">
                        <input class="formember" type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email">
                      </div>
                      <div class="">
                        <input type="password" class="formember" type="text" name="passwo" value=""  placeholder="Password">
                      </div>
                    </form>

                  </div>
                  <div id="sign2"class="row ">


                  <form class="formget " action="" method="post">
                    <div class="">
                      <input class="formember" type="text" name="pname" value="" placeholder="Personal Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="">
                      <input type="text" class="formember" type="text" name="lastname" value=""  placeholder="Lastname">
                    </div>
                    <div class="">
                      <input type="text" class="formember" type="text" name="phone" value=""  placeholder="Phone number">
                    </div>
                  </form>

                </div>
                <div id="sign3" class="row ">


                <form class="formget " action="" method="post">
                  <div class="">
                    <input class="formember" type="text" name="birth" value="" placeholder="Birthday YYYY-MM-DD">
                  </div>
                  <div class="">
                    <input type="text" class="formember" type="text" name="" value=""  placeholder="Profession">
                  </div>
                  <div class="">
                    <input type="text" class="formember" type="text" name="" value=""  placeholder="Nationality">
                  </div>
                </form>

              </div>

                    <br/>
                    <div class="card-feet">
                        <div class="sign-low">
                          <button id="btn-home" onclick="window.location.href='index.php'" class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="button" name="button">Home</button>
                          <button id="btn-previous"onclick="sesion.previous();" class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="button" name="button">Previous</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sign-low">
                          <button id="btn-next" class="btn btn-primary  pull-right" type="button" name="button" onclick="sesion.next();">Next</button>
                          <form class="" action="" method="post">
                            <input id="btn-finish" class='btn btn-primary btn-finish pull-right' type="submit" name='submitbutton' value="Finish"   ></input>
                          </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
<?php
$dbServerName = "remotemysql.com";
$dbUsername = "usr";
$dbPassword = "pss";
$dbName = "usr";

// create connection

$db = mysqli_connect($dbServerName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

if($_POST['submitbutton']) {

  $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_REQUEST['user']);
  $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_REQUEST['passwo']);
  $myemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_REQUEST['email']);
  $mypname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_REQUEST['pname']);
  $mylastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_REQUEST['lastname']);
  $myphone = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_REQUEST['phone']);
  $mybirth = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_REQUEST['birth']);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, passw, email,legalname,lastname,phone,birthdat)VALUES ('$myusername', '$mypassword', '$myemail', '$mypname','$mylastname','$myphone','$mybirth')";
  if ($db->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
    header("location: initx.php");
  } else {
      echo "Error: ";
  }

  $db->close();
}

 ?>
```

Estos son los errores:

> Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\signew.php on line 109
>   Notice: Undefined index: passwo in C:\xampp\htdocs\signew.php on line 110
>   Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\signew.php on line 111
>   Notice: Undefined index: pname in C:\xampp\htdocs\signew.php on line 112
>   Notice: Undefined index: lastname in C:\xampp\htdocs\signew.php on line 113
>   Notice: Undefined index: phone in C:\xampp\htdocs\signew.php on line 114
>   Notice: Undefined index: birth in C:\xampp\htdocs\signew.php on line 115

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español. Debes traducir tu pregunta al idioma oficial del sitio para que no termine cerrada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el identificador para $_POST primero identifica si fue recibida

```
if(isset($_POST['submitbutton']) && $_POST['submitbutton']) {
}
```

Y sustituye los request por post

```
$_REQUEST['propiedad']
//por
$_POST['propiedad']
```

Por último, y lo más importante, tienes diferentes forms en el html, el del button no contiene nada, entonces deberás 'ampliar' este form, solo debes usar uno, te recomiendo vaya como hijo del div.container

```
<div class="container">
<form class="formget " action="" method="post">
<!--El resto del contenido-->
<input id="btn-finish" class='btn btn-primary btn-finish pull-right' type="submit" name='submitbutton' value="Finish"   ></input>
</form>
<!--Cierras el resto de los divs-->
</div> <!--div.container -->
```

Comment: Gracias, eso resuelve una parte del problema, pero en sí, sigo sin poder sacar el dato de los inputs

Comment: Intenta con la edición de mi respuesta

Comment: justo eso había intentado ahorita, intente con mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['user']); y con ,$_POST['user']

Comment: ¿y se resolvió?

Comment: No, sigue marcandome undefined index, limpié el caché, y reinicié el xamp y no paso nada

Comment: Edité nuevamente mi respuesta, tienes varios forms, solo debes tener uno, borra las tags de forms

Comment: Gracias Hermano funcionó perfectamente