# Me sale un error al registrar un checkbox en el formulario con PHP

Tags: php, checkbox

resulta que mi tabla de usuario que se llama *users*, posee un campo llamado *view_email* que si este contiene un valor llamado *viewEmail* es porque el usuario autoriza a mostrar su correo electrónico en la pagina de detalles de producto, pero si contiene *notEmail* es porque el usuario no desea mostrar su email en dicha pagina.

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero resulta que tengo un formulario con un checkbox que registra en la tabla *users* en el campo *view_email* si el usuario desea o no desea mostrar su email.

**Código del formulario con el checkbox**

```
<form action="backend/view-email" class="col s12" method="POST">
                        <h1 class="flow-text center-align">Privacidad</h1>
                        <p class="center-align">¿Deseas mostrar tu Correo electr&oacute;nico en los detalles de tu producto ?</p>
                        <div class="row">

                        <!-- Mostrar si decea ver el email o no -->
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m12 xl12">

                            <?php if($viewEmail == '') : ?>
                                <p class="col s12">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="view" value="view" class="filled-in" checked="checked" />
                                        <span>Mostrar Correo electr&oacute;nico</span>
                                    </label>
                                </p>
                            <?php else : ?>
                                <p class="col s12">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="view" value="not view" class="filled-in" />
                                        <span>Mostrar Correo electr&oacute;nico</span>
                                    </label>
                                </p>
                            <?php endif ?>

                            <button type="submit" name="emailView" class="waves-effect blue btn col s5 m3 xl2">
                            <i class="material-icons left">save</i> Gualdar
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

**Backend del Formulario**

```
<?php

require_once('../conexion/conexion.php');

$errors = '';

if(isset($_POST['emailView'])){
    $view = $_POST['view'];

    // Validar que sean solo esos valores los que nos llegan
    if($view != 'view' || $view != 'not view'){
        $errors = 'Lo sentimos, pero ha ocurrido en error';
    }

    // Limpiar datos
    $view = htmlspecialchars($view);
    $view = trim($view);
    $view = filter_var($view, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    // Si todo se ha cumplido correctamente, entonces registrame la informacion
    if(empty($errors)){
        $statement = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE users SET view_email = '$view' WHERE email = '$email'"
        );
        $statement->execute(array(
            ':email' => $email,
            ':view' => $view
        ));

        // header('Location: ../configurations');
        var_dump($view);
    }
    // else{
    //     // header('Location: ../error.edit.user');
    // }
}
```

**Imagen con el error que me sale**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me ayuden, si necesitan mas información yo se las paso.
**Gracias y un cordial saludo**

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Notice: Undefined index: submitbutton](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/308730/notice-undefined-index-submitbutton)

Comment: Los checkbox no se mandan si no están marcados. Intenta mostrar un `var_dump($_POST);` para verificar que es lo que está llegando al servidor. Asegúrate que el archivo corresponde con lo que indicas en el `action` del formulario (al no tener extensión imagino que usas redirecciones, verifica que esa ruta redirige al archivo correcto). Otra cosa que veo rara es tantas etiquetas dentro de `form`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que el campo con el name "view" si no ha marcado nada, manda vacio. o si lo marca y luego lo desmarca, de la misma manera.

Seria cuestion que preguntes si existe o no algún dato que llegue:

```
if(isset($_POST['view'])){ 
   echo "tiene valor"; 
} else { 
   echo "no tiene valor"; 
}
```